# JavaScript engine is Single Threaded , Then How Web Workers Solves Multithreading?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

In some of the real time, we get unresponsive script error from the browser, so for resolving the problem, memory leaks have to use the web workers.

If Javascript is Single Thread, Javascript is a single threaded application which means cannot run more than script at a same time.

How Web Workers Support Multi-Threads.
What is the main Role of Web Workers?

JavaScript engine  is Single Threaded , Then How Web Workers Solves Multithreading?
 I am new to web workers, In Html5 Web workers Support  Web Workers: 
How will Simulate Threads.

post message => To send the message.
OnMessage => To Receive the Message.

Javascript promises support deferred handles for asynchronous operation and In angular2 Rxjs support Asynchronous Operation.

In Real-time app, where I have to add web workers, How to test the thread?

```
This is the sample code for web workers.

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           //while(true);

           var worker;

           if(window.Worker){
           console.log("workers are available");

           worker = new Worker('worker.js');
           worker.postMessage("Message gets Posted");
           worker.addEventListener('message',function(event){
           console.log(event);
           });
           console.log(worker);
           }
       </script>
    </body>
    </html>


Worker.js
self.addEventListener('message',function(event){
console.log(event);
});


can any One in much Detail.
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: @i need to know when to use web workers , what is the main role of web workers, How web workers solves multi-threading in any one real time scenario

Comment: You're on the right track.  Web workers do run a separate javascript engine in a separate thread.  However your question is vague and open-ended.

Answer (score 2):

Web workers run in separate thread's event loop. That's why you can't share any data with them and you have to copy/move data when posting messages.

The number of threads that are actually used depends on browser and platform.